# AWT preview in FOP 1.1

Tags: java, xslt, awt, apache-fop

I use Apache FOP for reporting in my application. It used to work ok with FOP 1.0, but because of a bug in combination with java webstart i had to upgrade to 1.1. The transformation works, i can output PDF or RTF directly without problems, but the preview does not work any more.

Transformation code:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(Loader.loadResource("Export/" + daten.getFO()).openStream()));
Source src = new DOMSource(daten.createXML());
Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
transformer.transform(src, res);
```

Old print preview code (working with 1.0):

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_FOP_AWT_PREVIEW);
```

With 1.1 this code doesn't open the preview window, nothing happens, no exceptions.
I tried to rewrite the preview like this:

```
AWTRenderer renderer = new AWTRenderer(foUserAgent);
foUserAgent.setRendererOverride(renderer);
PreviewDialog dlg = PreviewDialog.createPreviewDialog(foUserAgent, null, false);
renderer.setStatusListener(dlg);                
dlg.setVisible(true);
fop = fopFactory.newFop(foUserAgent);
```

With this changes i can see the preview window and get the correct amount of pages. The header and footer are also displayed but the content of the pages are empty.

Does anyone have an idea what changed between the 1.0 and 1.1? I couldn't find anything regarding the AWTRenderer. I don't think the problem is with the .fo file or the data, like i said transforming directly to a PDF file works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, i found a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2138) about this. This is fixed in the trunk version of FOP.